# VBA - improve the calculation efficiency when comparing cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following function to find out whether values of two cells are in two columns.
I have to compare 250 sets of two-cells with 6500 sets of two-cells.
Excel spent **30 seconds** to caculate the result.
Could I **improve the calculation efficiency**?

```
Public Function CompareWithTwoCells(twoCells As Range, twoCols As Range)
    Dim result As String
    result = "False"
    For n = 1 To twoCols.Rows.Count
        If twoCols(n, 1) = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

        If twoCells(1, 1) = twoCols(n, 1) And twoCells(1, 2) = twoCols(n, 2) Then
            result = "True"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    CompareWithTwoCells = result
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: You may find it better to ask this on Code Review...

Comment: I would copy your range into an array and perform the comparison on the array. Calculating from the memory is always gona be quicker than from a range in excel. Although I agree with @SolarMike .. this should be a code review question

Comment: It's difficult to squeeze any improvements if you want a UDF with exact string match with possible duplicates in `twoCols`. The standard optimizations are: copying out to array, nesting the `If` instead of using `And`, and setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. If you can relax the UDF requirement and change your function to work on `Selection` instead of `twoCells`, you can benefit by only running through `twoCols` once (simply concat the rows in `twoCols`, add them to a Dictionary, and check for existence).

Answer (score 0):

here's a first step of possible enhancements (explanations in comments):

```
Public Function CompareWithTwoCells(twoCells As Range, twoCols As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim firstVal As Variant, secondVal As Variant

    firstVal = twoCells(1, 1) ' store first cell value in a variable
    secondVal = twoCells(1, 2) ' store second cell value in a variable
    CompareWithTwoCells = "False"
    For Each cell In twoCols.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through first column not empty values
        If firstVal = cell.Value2 Then ' check one column fisrt
            If secondVal = cell.Offset(, 1) Then ' check second column only if first columns check is true
                CompareWithTwoCells = "True"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

a further significant enhancement would use array instead of ranges

Comment: This blocks my Excel

Comment: This is faster then your code. Is it you downvoting?

Comment: i've offset the downvote because this is a valid point. VBA seems to always test both conditions, unlike other languages where the `and` is not evaluated if the first condition is false.

Comment: I didn't downvote.  But it really blocked my Excel. I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just use `MATCH=MATCH`? (assuming `twoCells` is A1:B1 and `twoCols` is F1:G6500)

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A1,$F$1:$F$6500,0)=MATCH(B1,$G$1:$G$6500,0),FALSE)
```

This is almost instant on my machine.

Comment: There's an issue in the formula. If A1=F1,B1<>G1 and A1<>F2,B1=G2 and A1=F3,B1=G3, then the result becomes FALSE. The correct result I want is TRUE.

Comment: The MATCH function returns the index of the first value that is equal to `lookup_value`, and it does not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters when matching text values.

Answer (score -1):

As per @Zac's suggestion, add:

```
Dim twoCellsArr, twoColsArr
twoCellsArr = twoCells.Value2
twoColsArr = twoCols.Value2
```

Then change your `twoCells` and `twoCols` to `twoCellsArr` and `twoColsArr`.

If your `twoCols` doesn't change and you're doing repeated comparisons i recommend using a `Dictionary` to store the `twoCols.Value` as keys and the row number as values, then perform the lookup and comparing whether they are in the same row.

Comment: This is still slow. Slower.

Comment: have you tried the dictionary approach? you do realize that the slowness comes from writing repeated formulas that call your custom function to check against a range every time right?

Comment: Not me. twoCells and twoCols are arbitrary. I want to use the UDF everywhere. Indeed, it will call the UDF each twoCells.